# Stereochemistry in bicyclo compound

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

In the below bicyclo compound , there are two chiral carbon atoms. So, total combinations of configurations are four : RR, RS, SR, SS. However according to answer key , only two isomers of this compound exist. I am confused that how that can be ? Are some of the above configurations give identical compounds ? I cannot figure any simple symmetry which makes so.

Thanks very much.

[image]

Comment: The two chiral centres are not independent. The stereochemistry of one affects the other.

Comment: @An_Elephant Can you show how does it affects ?

Comment: It is trivial. You must be able to see it.

Comment: @An_Elephant It is not clear to me. Can you please write a detailed explanation ?

Comment: @DoraCake One approach: 1) assign configuration of the stereogenic centers in the structure shown. 2) imagine how the four substitutents around each of them should be attached to interconvert a centre presently (*R*) would be (*S*), and *vice versa* a centre (*S*) as one  (*R*).  How would this look like joining the pieces together?  Best thing for many is to build a model (no affiliation, but as an example [this one](https://hgs.maruzen.info/products/1000alpha-fundamental-organic-chemistry-set-student-guide)).

Comment: @DoraCake, to see that chiral centers in this compound are not independent try to draw a molecule with just one chiral carbon with opposite configuration. This way you will see that orientation of bond closing one of the rings from bicyclic system would be such that it will be impossible to connect it with the other atom that it is supposed to be connected with.

Comment: I think you could use a better textbook. What kind of lame question was that? There's certainly no stereoisomers at all, except on paper, but you could have some trouble even with drawing any.

Comment: This [site](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/isomers/RS14272/pinene.html#camphor) is instructive.